# Batch convert file format using a drag / drop executable?

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of files that I need to convert to a different file format using a program that is a standalone executable. You can either open the program and drag/drop the file on it that you want to convert or you can use the sendto command if I place the executable in the "sendto" directory in windows. The issue is there are a couple hundred files that I need to convert and if you drag / drop multiple files at one time or you send them using the "sendto" command it will only convert one of them and then stop. It appears that, while the program is actively converting a file, you have to wait for it to finish before it will accept the next file to convert.

I am looking for a way (preferably a batch file but, if necessary, a script) that will send a file to be converted and then wait a predetermined period of time before sending the next file for conversion. Ideally this program could search sub folders for the files that need to be converted.

Ex.

Search *.cue in sub folders

Sendto program.exe

Wait 3 minutes before sending the next file from the search above

I'm not sure if the above is possible. Would it make more sense to drag/drop multiple files in need of conversion on a batch file that would run a routine to accomplish the above?

Is it possible with a batch file?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a site for programmers helping each other on *specific* programming problems. Your post is a task request, which is off-topic here, unless you show us what you have tried so far and clearly describe where you are stuck. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Comment: I presume you are on Windows? And wonder why you tagged with `shell` which is normally associated with Linux/Unix?

Comment: What happens, if you run your EXE from commandline with a .CUE file as parameter? Does the command prompt wait for it to complete before the next prompt?

Comment: I apologize. I'm so new to this that I meant script when I added shell but didn't see an option for it in the Tags.

Comment: Yes I'm in a windows 10 enviroment. If I run the EXE from a commandline the GUI pops up. I'm not sure how to set .CUE as a parameter or if it's possible with this program?. Again, I apologize for being so lost. I'm still researching trying to figure this out.

Comment: try `<executable>.exe /?` for help. A program that takes a dropped filename usually also takes it as a parameter: `<executable>.exe "<filename>.cue"`. Please also try the full qualified filename as parameter (for example  `"C:\full path\filename.cue"`

Comment: Thank you. From a command line if I input "program.exe ABC.cue" then the program GUI pops up and converts that specific image. If I type Program.exe /h the GUI pops up. There doesn't appear to be any command line options with this executable.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /R %%a in (*.cue) do (
  Start cue2ccd.exe "%%~fa"
  timeout /t 45
  TASKKILL /F /IM cue2*
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `for` loop to process each file individually:

```
for %%a in (*.cue) do (
  program.exe "%%~fa"
  timeout /t 180
)
```

You can try to replace `program.exe "%%~fa"` with `start /wait program.exe "%%~fa"` and delete the `timeout` command. (`start /wait` is supposed to pause the script until the started program exits; for some GUI-programms that works, for some it doesn't.)

Comment: Stephan. Thanks!  The PROGRAM.EXE i have does not close automatically. If all the .CUE files with their associated tracks are in the ROOT with the PROGRAM.EXE and your BATCH file and I close the EXE manually then the 180 second timer kicks in and goes on to the next CUE. I found the batch command "taskill" (how to implement?) but that would need to happen after 180 secs at which time the process starts over again. Also, each CUE has several files linked with it so they are all in their own directories. Is there a way this batch will work on the CUE files in their directories?

Comment: Awesome sir. Thank you for the great start! I didn't know you could use /? with those commands.

Comment: `/?` works with nearly every command. Also there is an overview of all commands with sometimes a bit more information [here](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Very much appreciated. I actually have it working now and will do my best to dig deeper when I get stuck in the future. You've been a great help. Because the EXE wouldn't close on it's own found I needed to use the "start" command in order for the batch file to move on to the next line. Here is the final working batch. Thanks again Stephan!

Comment: ah - someone who actually using his brain to think and experiments on his own instead of just waiting for the perfect answer. I'm starting to like you `:)`